# Can´t get rid of object in render window

Tags: rendering

The white square and a couple other objects seem to stick in the picture, what ever i try to make them not seen, as my intention is to make only the white cloud visible. In the outliner i have tryed to restrict eny rendering that i just can find of any object from all scenes and as the cloud is a point dencity i have tryed to make the particle render not to render the emitter, i think i findt what object the white square is and restricted both, the rendering and scene visibility, but nothing seems to get rid of the objects´s. Any suggestions what it could be would be appreciated. [image]

Comment: Please upload your blend file so we can have a look for ourselves

Comment: I think i solved the problem .